# CHECK Constraint For Allowing X Duplicates In Column

Tags: mysql, database-design, check-constraints

I wasn't sure if this is something that can be done in a `CHECK` constraint or if this requires a Stored Procedure for validating during insert, but can a constraint be created to allow only X amount of duplicates in a column, where X > 1?

Something along the lines of:

```
CONSTRAINT limiter_chk CHECK (SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Ct FROM Mytable WHERE Id = Id AND Count < 50)
```

I'm aware the the above isn't valid, but just trying to show the type of constraint I'm describing.

Comment: Currently MySQL [parses but ignores](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2115497/3404097) CHECK constraints. Most DBMSs allow [only columns of a table in a condition in a CHECK constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6195881/3404097).

Comment: Recently learned that MySQL ignores the CHECK constraints (shortly after after I posted this)  That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business logic should be in the application, not the database.

However, you probably could write a `TRIGGER` to do what you are asking for.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the answer, but couldn't find anything definitive online.  Thanks for the confirmation.